# how to solve this problem

Tags: 0x, price

https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/price?sellToken=WETH&buyToken=WNXM&sellAmount=1000000000000000000

{"code":100,"reason":"Validation Failed","validationErrors":[{"field":"buyToken","code":1004,"reason":"Could not find token `WNXM`"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Use the token address instead of the token symbol. There’s ambiguity in symbols on many networks so we deprecated symbol usage